# Men managers VS. Man managers

Tags: vocabulary

I am really  wondering what is the difference between the two:

A. Men managers

B. Man managers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some context where you are thinking these phrases would be used? In different contexts, these could mean very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 1, implies this manager is in charge of a group of men in a company.
Sentence 2, means, this manager is Male, or he is brave/strong. 
A man who has the qualities that people think a man should have, such as being brave, strong...

Comment: @nima I think this answer is wrong. Without context, "men managers" and "man managers" are extremely ambiguous. (Native AmE.)

Answer (score 0):

Without context I would read them like this:

Men managers = managers who are men

Man managers = people who manage men

But with context this could be completely different.